404 with stripe embedded checkout
Hello I am attempting to create stripe embedded checkout in my nodejs, react, and mongodb environment. When clicking the checkout button the checkout window loads but returns errors.

`Error: EmbeddedCheckoutButton.jsx:12
POST http://localhost:5173/api/embedded-checkout 404 (Not Found)
(anonymous) @ EmbeddedCheckoutButton.jsx:12
e @ embedded-checkout-outer-6b8247795e3a6fa18b790b282c6410e5.js:1
Z @ embedded-checkout-outer-6b8247795e3a6fa18b790b282c6410e5.js:1
(anonymous) @ v3:1
Promise.then (async)
Ar @ v3:1
initEmbeddedCheckout @ v3:1
setStripeAndInitEmbeddedCheckout2 @ @stripe_react-stripe-js.js?v=b303af29:1437
(anonymous) @ @stripe_react-stripe-js.js?v=b303af29:1446
Promise.then (async)
(anonymous) @ @stripe_react-stripe-js.js?v=b303af29:1444
commitHookEffectListMount @ chunk-ZRJG7NCB.js?v=b303af29:16904
commitPassiveMountOnFiber @ chunk-ZRJG7NCB.js?v=b303af29:18152
commitPassiveMountEffects_complete @ chunk-ZRJG7NCB.js?v=b303af29:18125
commitPassiveMountEffects_begin @ chunk-ZRJG7NCB.js?v=b303af29:18115
commitPassiveMountEffects @ chunk-ZRJG7NCB.js?v=b303af29:18105
flushPassiveEffectsImpl @ chunk-ZRJG7NCB.js?v=b303af29:19486
flushPassiveEffects @ chunk-ZRJG7NCB.js?v=b303af29:19443
commitRootImpl @ chunk-ZRJG7NCB.js?v=b303af29:19412
commitRoot @ chunk-ZRJG7NCB.js?v=b303af29:19273
performSyncWorkOnRoot @ chunk-ZRJG7NCB.js?v=b303af29:18891
flushSyncCallbacks @ chunk-ZRJG7NCB.js?v=b303af29:9135
(anonymous) @ chunk-ZRJG7NCB.js?v=b303af29:18623
Show 15 more frames
Show less
embedded-checkout-outer-6b8247795e3a6fa18b790b282c6410e5.js:1 Uncaught (in promise) IntegrationError: fetchClientSecret failed with error "Unexpected token '<', "<!DOCTYPE "... is not valid JSON"
at embedded-checkout-outer-6b8247795e3a6fa18b790b282c6410e5.js:1:16996
(anonymous) @ embedded-checkout-outer-6b8247795e3a6fa18b790b282c6410e5.js:1
Promise.catch (async)
e @ embedded-checkout-outer-6b8247795e3a6fa18b790b282c6410e5.js:1
Z @ embedded-checkout-outer-6b8247795e3a6fa18b790b282c6410e5.js:1
(anonymous) @ v3:1
Promise.then (async)
Ar @ v3:1
initEmbeddedCheckout @ v3:1
setStripeAndInitEmbeddedCheckout2 @ @stripe_react-stripe-js.js?v=b303af29:1437
(anonymous) @ @stripe_react-stripe-js.js?v=b303af29:1446
Promise.then (async)
(anonymous) @ @stripe_react-stripe-js.js?v=b303af29:1444
commitHookEffectListMount @ chunk-ZRJG7NCB.js?v=b303af29:16904
commitPassiveMountOnFiber @ chunk-ZRJG7NCB.js?v=b303af29:18152
commitPassiveMountEffects_complete @ chunk-ZRJG7NCB.js?v=b303af29:18125
commitPassiveMountEffects_begin @ chunk-ZRJG7NCB.js?v=b303af29:18115
commitPassiveMountEffects @ chunk-ZRJG7NCB.js?v=b303af29:18105
flushPassiveEffectsImpl @ chunk-ZRJG7NCB.js?v=b303af29:19486
flushPassiveEffects @ chunk-ZRJG7NCB.js?v=b303af29:19443
commitRootImpl @ chunk-ZRJG7NCB.js?v=b303af29:19412
commitRoot @ chunk-ZRJG7NCB.js?v=b303af29:19273
performSyncWorkOnRoot @ chunk-ZRJG7NCB.js?v=b303af29:18891
flushSyncCallbacks @ chunk-ZRJG7NCB.js?v=b303af29:9135
(anonymous) @ chunk-ZRJG7NCB.js?v=b303af29:18623
Show 15 more frames
Show less
embedded-checkout-inner-4f38cb9b573b593aa25d64b0ef5f91aa7dbb2685.html:1 The resource https://js.stripe.com/v3/fingerprinted/js/vendor-ed806f99e961cd6de14fc83f461f1409.js was preloaded using link preload but not used within a few seconds from the window's load event. Please make sure it has an appropriate as value and it is preloaded intentionally.
embedded-checkout-inner-4f38cb9b573b593aa25d64b0ef5f91aa7dbb2685.html:1 The resource https://js.stripe.com/v3/fingerprinted/js/checkout-embedded-app-init-2883105900f567fce43f101c3d45e148.js was preloaded using link preload but not used within a few seconds from the window's load event. Please make sure it has an appropriate as value and it is preloaded intentionally.
embedded-checkout-inner-4f38cb9b573b593aa25d64b0ef5f91aa7dbb2685.html?publishableKey=pk_live_51P6gXHAOg135X54QQlQBrJkIn5nA79aKUj4s0iHnW9UYMfyo7VnJCT8OYNXSWP9UIHwotu21DsKBxbHEHMfwGhMP00DSgMa86o&onComplete=false&mids[guid]=e4ace878-71f6-46c7-acb0-33b30d2864d2c278f6&mids[muid]=896bd3b7-6373-4b58-8fe1-956fc7a3a10e73bb67&mids[sid]=0a221c25-31ea-4f66-8af7-a67401f03b25cc7246:8 Error: Timed out waiting for client secret
at embedded-checkout-inner-4f38cb9b573b593aa25d64b0ef5f91aa7dbb2685.html?publishableKey=pk_live_51P6gXHAOg135X54QQlQBrJkIn5nA79aKUj4s0iHnW9UYMfyo7VnJCT8OYNXSWP9UIHwotu21DsKBxbHEHMfwGhMP00DSgMa86o&onComplete=false&mids[guid]=e4ace878-71f6-46c7-acb0-33b30d2864d2c278f6&mids[muid]=896bd3b7-6373-4b58-8fe1-956fc7a3a10e73bb67&mids[sid]=0a221c25-31ea-          your text4f66-8af7-a67401f03b25cc7246:8:286505`

`> import express from 'express';

const router = express.Router();
import Stripe from 'stripe';
router.post('/api/embedded-checkout', async (req, res) => {
try {
const { priceId } = req.body;
const session = await Stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
payment_method_types: ['card'],
line_items: [
{
price: priceId,
},
],
mode: 'subscription',
success_url: ${req.headers.origin}/return?session_id={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID},
cancel_url: ${req.headers.origin}/cancel,
});
res.json({ id: session.id, client_secret: session.client_secret });
catch (error) {
console.error(error);
res.status(500).json({ message: error.message });
}
});
export default router;`


import { loadStripe } from "@stripe/stripe-js";
import { EmbeddedCheckoutProvider, EmbeddedCheckout } from "@stripe/react-stripe-js";
import { useCallback, useRef, useState } from "react";
export default function EmbeddedCheckoutButton() {
const stripePromise = loadStripe("pk_live_51P6gXHAOg135X54QQlQBrJkIn5nA79aKUj4s0iHnW9UYMfyo7VnJCT8OYNXSWP9UIHwotu21DsKBxbHEHMfwGhMP00DSgMa86o");
const [showCheckout, setShowCheckout] = useState(false);
const modalRef = useRef(null);
const fetchClientSecret = useCallback(() => {
return fetch("/api/embedded-checkout", {
method: "POST",
headers: {
"Content-Type": "application/json",
},
body: JSON.stringify({ priceId: "price_1P7D6PAOg135X54QFHUDmSgG" }),
})
.then((res) => res.json())
.then((data) => data.client_secret);
[]);
const options = { fetchClientSecret };
const handleCheckoutClick = () => {
setShowCheckout(true);
modalRef.current && modalRef.current.showModal();
};
const handleCloseModal = () => {
setShowCheckout(false);
modalRef.current && modalRef.current.close();
};
return (


Open Modal with Embedded Checkout



Embedded Checkout

{showCheckout && (



)}




Close






);
}
`

   import express from "express";
 import mongoose from 'mongoose';
 import dotenv from 'dotenv';
 import userRoutes from './routes/user.route.js';
import authRoutes from './routes/auth.route.js';
import stripeRoutes from './routes/stripe.route.js';
import stripeEmbeddedRoutes from './routes/embedded-checkout.route.js';
// Create an instance of the Stripe API client

       dotenv.config();


 mongoose

.connect(process.env.MONGO)
.then(() => {
console.log('Connected to MongoDB');
})
.catch((err) => {
console.log(err);
});
const app = express();

app.use(express.json());
app.use('/api/user', userRoutes);
app.use('/api/auth', authRoutes);
app.use('/api/stripe', stripeRoutes);
app.use('/api/stripe/success', stripeRoutes);
app.use('/api/stripe/cancel', stripeRoutes);
app.use ('/api/embedded-checkout', stripeEmbeddedRoutes);
app.listen(3000, () => {
console.log('server is running on port 3000!');
});
 app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
  const statusCode = err.statusCode || 500;
  const message = err.message || 'Internal Server Error';
 console.log(err);
     return res.status(statusCode).json({
  success: false,
  message,
   statusCode,
   })
     })



Based on the error, the POST request you're making to http://localhost:5173/api/embedded-checkout appears to be failing. You should double check your code to see if that route actually exists.

Yes the route does exist. Idk why the code above is appearing the way it does.
